# Operating System Question Kernel XV6 Interrupt and Timer Interrupt

Tags: operating-system, xv6

I am kind of confusing about the interrupt. Is there anyone can help to explain the difference between interrupt and time interrupt?

what happened when Interrupt and time interrupt?

Answer (score 0):

An interrupt is an interrupt. Most processors allow the operating system to schedule an interrupt to be triggered after a specified period of time.